# Which was the first story to feature a human manned mecha "robot"?

Tags: history-of, robots, mecha

In the Pacific Rim live action movies (2013 - 2018) they feature human manned mecha "robots". Before this, there were many others live actions / animated series featuring this, Evangelion (1995) , Robotech (1985) , Macross (1982),  Star Wars (1983 - 1980 , dont recall seeing any of them in the 1977 movie) , Gundam (1979) , etc.

But which was the first story to feature a human manned mecha "robot"?

Comment: Would you consider the powered armor from Starship Troopers (1959) to be a mech?  Or are you requiring that the mech be much larger than human size as a parameter?

Comment: Seconding @VBartilucci, but perhaps rewording: Is there a difference between mecha and powered armor?

Comment: Is there a reason this doesn't answer the question? (Is it missing something you're looking for..?): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecha#Early_history

Comment: One of the Sinbad ones from the 70's ;)

Comment: Technically, The trojan horse could count...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Wikipedia entry for mecha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecha#Early_history) (as suggested by wcullen in a comment above - remember to upvote that comment), we find mention of Edward S. Ellis' 1868 story *The Steam Man of the Prairies*. Quoting from [the novel's Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Steam_Man_of_the_Prairies):

> Ethan Hopkins and Mickey McSquizzle—a "Yankee" and an "Irishman"—encounter a colossal, steam-powered man in the American prairies. This steam-man was constructed by Johnny Brainerd, a teenaged boy, who uses the steam-man to carry him in a carriage on various adventures.

The steam man seems to fit all the requirements of a mecha, and given the age of the story, it is very likely to be the first.

[image]